# R: Speed up API calls

Tags: json, r, api, steam-web-api

I am writing code to collect data from the Steam API (documentation: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API).

Particularly, I use the `fromJSON()` function from the `jsonlite` package in `[R]`.

However, I have the feeling that the code is slow, and that the bottleneck is the actual calling of the API. I am currently able to do around 7.500-10.000 calls an hour, resulting in around 2-3 calls per second. This feels slow. Is it possible to speed this up, and if so, how?

Two things I found already is that it may be necessary to close the connection after opening it (cf. http://www.firaja.cc/steam-web-api-right-way.html). Also, the API allows json (what I use now) but also XML and CSV outputs, maybe it is better to use one of the latter two? Any other possible solutions?

Comment: steams limit is 100,000 per day, so you might be hitting their rate limit. Otherwise, you'd need to paste some of your code here so we can see what might be slowing it down.

Comment: Recommend using a proper http client - `httr` - Will deal with handles for you, and re-using handles as it does may speed things up a bit. See also `write_stream` in `httr` for writing streaming responses